# What is difference between [UIButton setTitleForDisabled:] and [UIButton setTitle:forState]

Tags: ios, objective-c

Consider there is a `button` which is a instance of UIButton

What is difference between

```
[button setTitleForDisabled:@"Title"];
```

and

```
[button setTitle:@"Title" forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
```

When disable the button with

```
button.enabled = NO;
```

It get difference `button.textLabel.text`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never seen [button setTitleForDisabled:@"Title"]; method. It doesn't show on my documentation. Maybe you have it as a category? Anyways, based on the name I would assume you're right. [button setTitleForDisabled:@"Title"]; is [button setTitle:@"Title" forState:UIControlStateDisabled]; when button.enabled = NO;

Comment: Yeah, that's defined in a customized category. And I found the logic in there.